# How to reserve a package name in pub?

Tags: dart

I am developing a (soon to be) open source library. I found the name I want to use and checked that there's no (yet) a package using that name.

Is there any way to reserve that name, possibly without releasing an incomplete project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty package with that name and publish it,
with a README.md that explains the status.

> without releasing an incomplete project

Nope.